# Переписать устаревший MySQL на PDO/MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

Ниже вы видите код c устаревшим mysql, помогите это все изменить в PDO или mysqli. 
Самая основная головная боль это то, что я не могу сделать рабочие ссылки с циклом while.

```
<?
$title = "Каталог";
$color = "#aaddff";

include("header.php");
include("connect.php");

$strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM publishers ORDER BY name_publ";
$result1 = mysql_query($strSQL1) or die("Не могу выполнить запрос!");

$strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY name_cat";
$result2=mysql_query($strSQL2) or die("Не могу выполнить запрос!");
?>

<tr>
  <td>
    <table border=0 width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%">
          <center><h3>Издатели</h3></center>
          <ul>
            <?
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
              {?>
              <li><a href="show.php?type=1&id_publ=
                  <?print $row["id_publ"];?>">
                  <?print $row["name_publ"];?></a>
              </li>
            <?}?>
          </ul>
        </td>

        <td width="50%"><center><h3>Категории</h3></center>
          <ul>
            <?while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
            {?>
              <li><a href="show.phtml?type=2&id_cat=
                <?print $row["id_cat"];?>">
                <?print $row["name_cat"];?></a>
              </li>
            <?}?>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>

<?
include("footer.php");
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Вообщем кому интересно, я хочу написать интренет магазин на php и sql. Выбрал книжку http://kek.ksu.ru/EOS/Tests/book/Ec2.pdf ,она 2010 года. Очень многое устарело, но зато полно практических примеров.

Answer (score -1):

Подключение к базе и выполнение запроса

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Ошибка ". mysqli_error($link));
$query ="SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка ". mysqli_error($link));
if($result)
{
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {  
       $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
    }
}
```

Cсылки:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
while($count<10)
{
   echo "<a href='http://site.com/".$count."'/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: так не работает